# How to create bounding box around each characters?

Tags: python, image, text, python-imaging-library, draw

I have this function that I want to be like draw line between each characters. I have approaches like taking a vertical straight line with passing argument- co-ordinate(x,y) sequences axis but not able to fix that and confused where can make some changes. Any help?

```
def draw_text_on_bg(self, word, font, bg):
    """
    Draw word in the center of background
    :param word: word to draw
    :param font: font to draw word
    :param bg: background numpy image
    :return:
        np_img: word image
        text_box_pnts: left-top, right-top, right-bottom, left-bottom
    """
    bg_height = bg.shape[0]
    bg_width = bg.shape[1]

    word_size = self.get_word_size(font, word)
    word_height = word_size[1]
    word_width = word_size[0]

    offset = font.getoffset(word)

    pil_img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(bg))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_img)

    # Draw text in the center of bg
    text_x = int((bg_width - word_width) / 2)
    text_y = int((bg_height - word_height) / 2)

    if self.is_bgr():
        word_color = self.get_word_color()
    else:
        word_color = self.get_gray_word_color(bg, text_x, text_y, word_height, word_width)

    if apply(self.cfg.random_space):
        text_x, text_y, word_width, word_height = self.draw_text_with_random_space(draw, font, word, word_color,
                                                                                   bg_width, bg_height)
        np_img = np.array(pil_img).astype(np.float32)
    else:
        if apply(self.cfg.seamless_clone):
            np_img = self.draw_text_seamless(font, bg, word, word_color, word_height, word_width, offset)
        else:
            self.draw_text_wrapper(draw, word, text_x - offset[0], text_y - offset[1], font, word_color)
            # draw.text((text_x - offset[0], text_y - offset[1]), word, fill=word_color, font=font)

            np_img = np.array(pil_img).astype(np.float32)

    text_box_pnts = [
        [text_x, text_y],
        [text_x + word_width, text_y],
        [text_x + word_width, text_y + word_height],
        [text_x, text_y + word_height]
    ]

    return np_img, text_box_pnts, word_color
```

Here's sample [image data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNBoN.png),in which trying to make some changes.

Here's the sample[text img data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtROu.png) pattern I am looking exactly. please help me on that I am totally stuck!

I used to generate textimage data by synthtext library [repo](https://github.com/Sanster/text_renderer). In which I need to changes the above function it present on textrenderer/renderer.py

Comment: You could use the [`ImageDraw.textsize()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.textsize) function to get the size of each character in the string, and then use that to determine where to draw each bounding box with [`ImageDraw.rectangle()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.rectangle).

Comment: thanks for the response @martineau but I am new in python programming, not able to understand how can apply this?

Comment: yea, that's why I have shared the above function in which i am looking for some changes as i mentioned in the query, thanks, I respect your time.